# Web: Animated clouds -- overflow and middle mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a website with a "toony" feel and, decided to have animated clouds that went from left to right. The only problem with this is that I can middle click over to where my off-screen clouds are. Is there a way to disable middle mouse click or hide the cloud until it is needed on-screen?

Note: the container already has: `overflow: hidden;`

This is my current HTML:

```
    <div id="clouds">
        <!-- Background Clouds -->
        <div class="cloud background medium left-fast" style="top: 2%;"></div>
        <div class="cloud background small left-slow" style="left: -5%; top: 20%;"></div>
        <div class="cloud background large left-slower" style="top: 7.5%;"></div>
        <div class="cloud background small left-slowest" style="left: 14%; top: 18%;"></div>

        <!-- Foreground Clouds -->
        <div class="cloud medium fast" style="top: 2%;"></div>
        <div class="cloud small slow" style="left: 5%; top: 20%;"></div>
        <div class="cloud large slower" style="top: 7.5%;"></div>
        <div class="cloud small slowest" style="left: -14%; top: 18%;"></div>
    </div>
```

and my current CSS:

```
/* Clouds container */
#clouds{
    width: 100%; height: 20%;
    padding: 100px 0;
}

/* General Cloud */

.cloud {
    /* General properties of a cloud */
    background: url('../images/clouds.png');
    position: absolute; 
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Background Clouds */

.cloud.background.small {
    /* Appearance */
    background-position: -23px -194px;
    width: 250px; height: 85px;
}

.cloud.background.medium {
    /* Appearance */
    background-position: -666px -149px;
    width: 279px; height: 119px;
}

.cloud.background.large {
    background-position: -543px -329px;
    width: 360px; height: 149px;
}

/* Foreground clouds */

.cloud.small {
    background-position: -321px -24px;
    width: 246px; height: 91px;
}

.cloud.medium {
    /* Appearance */
    background-position: -628px -18px;
    width: 312px; height: 81px;
}

.cloud.large {
    /* Appearance */
    background-position: -27px -22px;
    width: 259px; height: 104px;
}

/* Background Cloud Animations and Speeds */

.cloud.left-fast {
    /* Fast animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear infinite;
}

.cloud.left-slow {
    /* Slow animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear 3s infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear 3s infinite;
}

.cloud.left-slower {
    /* Slower animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear 7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear 7s infinite;
}

.cloud.left-slowest {
    /* Slowest animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear 12s infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovementBackground 40s linear 12s infinite;
}

/* Foreground Cloud Animations and Speeds */

.cloud.fast {
    /* Fast animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear infinite;
}

.cloud.slow {
    /* Slow animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear 3s infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear 3s infinite;
}

.cloud.slower {
    /* Slower animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear 7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear 7s infinite;
}

.cloud.slowest {
    /* Slowest animation */
    -webkit-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear 12s infinite;
    -moz-animation: cloudMovement 40s linear 12s infinite;
}

/* Animations */

@-webkit-keyframes cloudMovement {

    0% {
    margin-left: -30%;
    visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
    margin-left: 110%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cloudMovement {
    0% {
    margin-left: -30%;
    visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
    margin-left: 110%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloudMovementBackground {

    0% {
    margin-left: 110%;
    }

    5% {
    visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
    margin-left: -50%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cloudMovementBackground {
    0% {
    margin-left: 110%;
    }

    8% {
    visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
    margin-left: -50%;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with both of your suggested approaches should work. I am going to help you with the second suggestion though. You can use Java script to disable pretty much any standard behavior. The key to this is the `[preventDefault][1]` function.

Here is an example that might work for you. (You should add it to your html page in the header section)

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.button === 1){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }, true);

</script>
```

This should capture any middle clicks including the scroll wheel. I it might still be possible to scroll around using the left or right button in some browsers.

It might also work to use the css property overflow-x. If you set overflow-x: hidden for the a div containing the clouds it should not allow rendering outside the page. You could also set that div to be fixed so that the clouds don't scroll when you scroll down.

```
#id {
overflow-x:hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

I hope this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Cool I had a bit of trouble testing it on SO webpage. But I thought It might still work. Could be there are some problems with mousewheel clicks still but then again that might be ok.